# Coolant fluid in canister purge valve line

Tags: hyundai, evap, santa-fe, purge-solenoid

I have a 2008 Hyundai Santa Fe GLS, and my check engine light came on because of a failure to purge code. I took off the canister purge valve and immediately thought I had misidentified it, because there was coolant fluid in the line.

I went back to the diagrams and verified I had the correct part.  I put a 9-volt battery on the leads, and sure enough, it would not open.

I have the new valve, which works fine with the 9-volt test, but I'm a little concerned I have a larger problem...

Why would there be coolant fluid there? It's not even close to any of the manifold sections through which the coolant runs. Plus, it's on the canister side, not the release side. Could it just be bad gas that ***looks*** like coolant fluid (I didn't taste test it, but it is green :)?

Comment: Bad gas wouldn't be green... Is the car's coolant green?  I've seen a lot of pink lately, so I'd at least check the color.  If you still have some, can you at least smell it?  Of course I guess it might have absorbed some gas smell...

Comment: May be a leak in the throttle body. Though it's odd that the purge valve would have any fluid in it. Can you take a picture of the line and the fluid? Maybe at some point someone attached a coolant line to the purge valve for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes, the car's coolant is green. I did smell it, and it smelled like coolant. it even separated from the gas when it hit the ground, and it was clearly neon green

Comment: @Ben I still haven't figured out how the coolant got there, and it fell out when I tried to take a picture, but replacing the throttle body has fixed the problem. I don't even see where a coolant line attaches there, but I haven't seen any since I replaced it.

Comment: @Dexter  That's great, glad it's resolved.  Perhaps you can answer your question and award it to yourself?   Thanks!

Comment: @Dexter I had a similar experience on my Lexus IS250. 1) I cleaned throttle body due to ignition off on cold start the rpm idle can't keep up. 2) I saw white smoke near Exhaust Manifold. 3) Leak tested head gasket no problem 4) White smoke from exhaust tail 5) Engineer cleaned the fuel tank 6) No more white smoke on both (Exhaust Manifold and exhaust tail) but hard time me to fuel gas thought canister also went bad. 7) Just check the canister's vent line tube, had couple drop of pink coolant like 50ml (not strong smell). Will replace throttle body fix the problem?